# MS Excel. How to get around pivoting data that has blank placeholder columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, data-validation

I've been asked to produce a dashboard based on a data set that looks something like the screenshot below. The dates are the column headings and there are blank and placeholder columns in between each of the sections. They are adding columns each month as they go along. I am unable to create a pivot table based on the current data set, because of the blank column headings. How can I get around this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: create a sub set of the data, then pivot off the subset

Comment: Thanks @PeterH
Would you mind clarifying what you mean by "create a sub set"?
Do you mean to have a separate tab for each of the Sales, Target and Variance sections?

Answer (score 0):

> How to get around pivoting data that has blank placeholder columns?

**You can not.**

Excel can't create a pivot table from non-contiguous range. A workaround can be to add content to empty headers having the same font colour as background colour.

Comment: Also this data is effectively already half-pivoted. You need a row for every data item, and a column for every variable - year, month, store, type (Sales, Target, Variance) etc

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can create a subset as mentioned in my comment.

See image below.

Say columns `A:F` represent your original data.

L:N will represent the subset.

In CELL L1 use `=A1`, in M1 use `=D1`, and so on.

Or use `=IF(A1="","",A1)` this way you can drag the formula a lot more rows than the orginal data, in anticipation that in the future more data will be added.

Then you can create the pivot off of the subset.

When i use subsets i will often bring in `INDEX` `MATCH` etc. you can even add other conditions into the subset that you wouldn't otherwise want in the original data.

I will often have the sub set on another tab, and then usually hide the tab, this way the original data can be used/updated as intended and the pivot can run also.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this, @PeterH. If I have 3 subsets, would you recommend I format them as three separate tables?

Comment: Also, may I ask what your advice would be when working with dates in Column Headings? I understand that the ideal solution would be to unpivot the data and have a row for each date but unfortunately this is not an option at this stage as there are currently over 100 headings representing dates :(